# Route [] not defined in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Currently I am working on a big laravel project. There is login form on main page. When I login getting error `Route [] not defined.` & url was `https://dummyurl/user/login`.

But `user/login` Url is already defined as :

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'User'], function() {
Route::post('/user/login', ['as' => 'getlogin',
    'uses' => 'UserController@loginCheck'
    ]);
});
```

When I refresh that page again it showing user as logged & getting following error:

```
314 /dummyurl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php Route [] not defined.Something Went Wrong Please Try Again...!
```

Comment: You didnt filled in a `route()` parameter. Perhaps on the page when you're logged in and getting redirected to

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: `Route [] not defined` means that you didnt filled in a route somewhere in your code. So instead of `route('my.route.to.something')` is in your case somewhere `route('')`

Comment: @DonnyvanV how can i find that its very big project any idea & also checked laravel log it is not showing any file name

Comment: It can be anywhere... Use a debugbar, a good IDEA to do a search for all `route('`  and check them

Comment: @DonnyvanV there is no such case I have checked

Comment: Did you checked your controllers? Check also for variables that are a empty string. Or a `return redirect()->route('')`